# Perform action on elements added by AJAX

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dynamic, element

I have a page with a lightbox on it, using a lightbox plugin. The elements I want to turn into a lightbox are simply selected and altered like this:

```
$(".lightbox").find("a").live('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".lightbox").find("a").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
    });
});
```

I know it's not the cleanest way, but it works for now. My real question is, how can I run `$(".lightbox").fancybox(...)` on elements added to the page by AJAX? I could put the `.fancybox()` stuff inside the `success:` part of the AJAX call, but I'm looking for a cleaner, "fire and forget" solution; one piece of code I can write that applies to all future elements. `.live()` is perfect here, apart from the fact that you have to bind it to an event. I guess the even here is `create`, which doesn't exist.

So, how can I run a function on elements added to the page by AJAX now, or in the future without having to put lots of bits of code all over the place?

Thanks,

James

Comment: i think ajax call back might be one of the options as you mentioned other give a class name and bind them using live

Comment: I don't see what's so bad about organizing your "preparation" code so that it can be called whenever it's needed, and then simply doing that from the "success" handler(s) of dynamic updates. It's a pretty simple architectural problem to solve: just treat page load time as being just another non-special instance of "prepare stuff for action".

Comment: @kobe: Thanks for that. I think I'll go with adding the code into the `success:` call; It's not too hard, and if I put it in a function it will be easier to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another layer of abstraction above your jQuery ajax call.  This layer will make the ajax call for you and scan your result, adding the lightbox as necessary.  Here is what I have in mind:

**1.**

```
function lightBoxAjaxRequest(requestObj) {
    if (requestObj.success) {
        var requestObjCopy = $.clone(requestObj);  // clone request object

        requestObjCopy.success = function add$lightbox$to$response(html) {
             // Add "html" to the page...
             // Call lightbox code here, on newly added HTML
             requestObj.success(html); // Trigger original success handler
        };

        $.ajax(requestObjCopy);
    }
    else {
        $.ajax(requestObj);
    }
};
```

Something like that maybe?  I don't know how well that would work in practice though.  It seems like you want to always trigger some function after something has been added to the DOM.

**Alternatively**

You could also create a wrapper around `innerHTML` to do the work for you:

**2.**

```
function addHtmlToDomWithLightbox(domElement, html) {
    if (typeof domElement === "string") {
        domElement = $("#" + domElement);
    }

    domElement.html(html);

    // Add lightbox here
    domElement.find("a").fancyBox({});
};
```

You would call `addHtmlToDomWithLightbox` in all of your success functions (instead of adding the html via the jQuery `html` method).  Note that the method name is long and verbose, you could change it and place the method where ever you want.  I just made it verbose for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort you've put into this answer! I really appreciate it, however I've gone with the simpler option of calling a function when the AJAX request returns. Besides, I don't have to do it in many places.